# F# equivalent of the C# 'object' keyword

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to port an existing c# to f# and would I am getting stuck on porting this c# line:

```
public object myInnerOject
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In C# `object` is just a type name referring to `System.Object`. In F#, you can either use this full .NET name or a type alias `obj`.

Now, regarding a field declaration - there are various ways to write that depending on the context. Also, it is a good practice to initialize all fields in F#, so it would be useful to see larger context of your code.

However, you may write this:

```
type A() = 
  let mutable (myInnerObj:obj) = null
```

This creates a private field `myInnerObj` of type `System.Object` initialized to `null`, which is mutable can can be assigned later (`myInnerObj <- new Random()`, for example). I used example with private field, because public fields are generally discouraged in .NET.

Comment: Doh! Always the simple stuff! Thank you very much; Y - I am on page with the rest of the declaration... for some reason I had a mind freeze and my f# texts are out on loan to a buddy...

Answer (score 6):

@Tomas is right.  You may also want to check out these blogs:

[The basic syntax of F# - types](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1077.entry)

[What does this C# code look like in F#?](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry)